# react-router v6: Navigate to a URL with searchParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router v6. I want to navigate to a URL that has searchParams, but I'm not seeing a way to do this out of the box. `useNavigate` allows me to navigate to a URL by passing in a string. `useSearchParams` allows me to set searchParams on the current page.

I could generate the searchParams using `createSearchParams` and then convert it to a string and append it to the end of the URL with a `?` in between, but that seems like a hack.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();

// listing?foo=bar
navigate("listing", {
    params: {
        foo: "bar"
    }
});
```

My hacky workaround:

```
function useNavigateParams() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (url: string, params: Record<string, string | string[]>) => {
        const searchParams = createSearchParams(params).toString();
        navigate(url + "?" + searchParams);
    };
}

const navigateParams = useNavigateParams();

navigateParams("listing", {
    foo: "bar"
});
```

Did I miss something from the documentation?

Comment: to make things less confusing for this conversation, in react-router speak "params" are the variables in the URI aka `/:id` is `params.id`, what you're talking about is commonly refered to as the `location.search` part aka `query-string`. there's a nice helper library that's fairly common for these ops, but I don't think that react-router ships with this stringing / parsing utilites https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

Comment: As the question appears to be about `react-router-v6`, you might want to update the tag (v4)

Comment: you can use 'useRouter' from (https://usehooks.com)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Update**

It's no longer necessary to prepend `?` to search (as of ~September 2021):

```js
import { createSearchParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate({
    pathname: "listing",
    search: createSearchParams({
        foo: "bar"
    }).toString()
});
```

This isn't quite as simplified as I'd like, but I think it's the closest we can get currently. `navigate` *does* support passing in a search query string (not an object).

```js
import { createSearchParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate({
    pathname: "listing",
    search: `?${createSearchParams({
        foo: "bar"
    })}`
});
```

Source: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7743#issuecomment-770296462

Comment: The above quoted method works for the first time .i.e, from
Parent1 > child1
When I use the same logic, by using
Parent2, Child2, its getting navigated to "Child1" instead of "Child2"
The route set for parent1 and child 1 is
<Route path="/parent1" element={<Parent1 />} />
<Route path="/parent1/child1" element={<child1 />} />
<Route path="/parent2" element={<Parent2 />} />
<Route path="/parent2/child2" element={<child2 />} />
The params for Child 1 and Child2 are set as quoted in github
navigate ({pathname: "listing",search: '?' + createSearchParams({ foo: "bar" })})

Comment: Hello, I tried using your approach but whenever it redirects, the query parameters are removed. Do you have any idea why? Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

What you have is looks fine to me. Using the [generatePath](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/generate-path) and [createSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/create-search-params) utilities it may be a little cleaner, but it is still the same basic idea.

```
import { generatePath, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

...

const useNavigateParams = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (url: string, params: Record<string, string | string[]>) => {
    const path = generatePath(":url?:queryString", {
      url,
      queryString: createSearchParams(params).toString()
    });
    navigate(path);
  };
};
```

If you think about it this isn't much of a hack, the URL needs to be defined *somewhere*, whether it's the path params or part of the query string, you still need to provide that detail and build a path string to navigate to.

## Demo - POC

[image: Edit react-router-v6-navigate-to-a-url-with-searchparams]

RRDv6.4 update

```
import { createSearchParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

...

const useNavigateParams = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (pathname, params) => {
    const path = {
      pathname,
      search: createSearchParams(params).toString()
    };
    navigate(path);
  };
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-navigate-to-a-url-with-searchparams (forked)]

Comment: Hello, I tried using your approach but whenever it redirects, the query parameters are removed. Do you have any idea why? Thank you!

Comment: @maryyyyyyy Dunno, we would probably need to see your code to see what it's doing. If you like you can create a new post on stackoverflow with the relevant [mcve] and details regarding the issue and any debugging steps you've taken. Feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to your post and I can take a look when available.

Answer (score 13):

To do this elegantly, you should use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hook instead of `useNavigate`.

As specified in the doc:

> The setSearchParams function works like navigate, but only for the search portion of the URL. Also note that the second arg to setSearchParams is the same type as the second arg to navigate.

```js
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

...

const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams()

...

const handleClick = () => {
    searchParams.set('foo', 'bar');
    setSearchParams(searchParams)
}
```

Comment: Using `setSearchParams()` at the same time as `navigate()` does not work, the route gets messed up.

Comment: @derpedy-doo that's the problem I've faced too, one always overwrites the other so you either navigate to the new path *or* you get the search params on the current path

Answer (score 2):

Tested with `react-router-dom@6.14.0`

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate({ pathname: '/otherpage/', search: "?param1=123" });
```

Or with `createSearchParams` from `react-router-dom`

```js
import { createSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate({ 
  pathname: '/otherpage/', 
  search: createSearchParams({ params1: "123" }).toString() 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance you might want to preserve the search in the URL and only change some values. `useSearchParams` doesn't seem to work for this purpose, because the first value returned in the hook is an empty object, while it would make more sense for it populated with the search params which are already in the URL. Bad design imho. However, I found a way to achieve the expected behaviour and only change a portion of the parameters using the react router in combination with [serialize-query-params](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-query-params)

```typescript
// this goes right below the component declaration,
// where all the hooks are called
const navigate = useNavigate();

....
// this goes inside the function to change the search
// here we merge the new param with the current ones
const newLocation = updateInLocation(
  { foo: 'bar' },
  location
);

navigate(newLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use both of them in an easy way:

```js
import { useNavigate, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

...

const [searchBarParams, setSearchBarParams] = useSearchParams();
const navigate = useNavigate();

...


const handleChange = (event, value) => {
    navigate("/")
    searchBarParams.set("foo",value)
    setSearchBarParams(searchBarParams);
}
```